# Mongod not being updated / not update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

this question may sound way more stupid than it is, but how to update mongod?

Bear with me and take a minute to read...

I just started to watch some Node lectures, and in the first lecture the teacher asks to install node and mongo.... ok, I already had Node installed, so, let's just install mongo... go to Mongodb website, download the latest Windows version available (mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.6.3-signed.msi) install and ok...

Then, before do something, the teacher asks to open my terminal and type some

> mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath d:\mongo\data\db --logpath
>   d:\mongo\log\mongo.log --logappend --install --rest

returns

> Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--rest' try 'mongod
>   --help' for more information

Ok... rest is deprecated, should not use it anymore.... google a little bit, now I should use a lib (Crest).... ok... let's npm it

> npm install -g crest

Exactly as in readme... what it returns?

> npm WARN deprecated mongodb@1.2.14: Please upgrade to 2.2.19 or higher
>   npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.0: Use uuid module instead

How on earth something I just installed on the latest version, is completely outdated?

Ok, let's breathe a while... google "how to update mongod to latest version?"... download a 290mb zip file, delete the /bin content and throw the files there... ok, sounds reasonable... move the files to another folder (I am not stupid to just delete the files, I'd rather to make backup instead sorry)...

Try to install Crest again... same error...

ok.... NPM on mongod

> npm install -g mongod@latest
>
> - mongod@2.0.0
>
> updated 1 package in 5.28s

Install Crest again, same error....

This is not a fresh windows installation, but is only me who uses this computer and this computer never seen Mongodb installation since it last format... this a fresh Mongodb installation...

Out of ideas now guys.... any light in here??

Cheers

Comment: Mongod that you installed using npm is a different package to be used from within the node application

Comment: Yeah... I noticed that after I installed it =\

Answer (score 0):

The current official version of mongodb is 3.6 you can check by the following command: `mongo --version`. You can download [here](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community).
I wouldnt recommend using REST option for development, if yiu want it to look at the db there are better alternative. I use the following:

- for development on node: [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose)
- Database Client: [studio 3t](https://studio3t.com), [Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#compass)

  I dont think you will be needing crest if u are using thoes. But if u do just reinstall mongo from the official site.

Comment: - C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongo --version
- MongoDB shell version v3.6.3-83-g37bb673018
- git version: 37bb673018dc891bf5c17f5c5a80f175bb8ccba2
- OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016
- allocator: tcmalloc
- modules: none
- build environment:
- distmod: 2008plus-ssl
- distarch: x86_64
- target_arch: x86_64

Comment: It seems to be the same version from official MongoDB website... and Compass is already installed, the MongoDB installation asks to install it. I don't know what the REST flag is, I was just following along the lecture, but this flag is not available anymore. It can't be used, so I need to use Crest, according the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#crest-node-js).